# For Each loop using PowerPack OvalShapes

Tags: vb.net

I have a GroupBox with a bunch of OvalShapes in it called OvalShape1, OvalShape2, etc...

I am trying to create a For Each loop to change the color of each individualy. My code is this:

```
For Each childcontrol As OvalShape In GroupBox1.Controls
    Dim opOv As OvalShape = childcontrol
    Randomize()
    opOv.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromWin32(RGB(rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256)))
Next
```

This gives me this exception:

> "Cannot associate object of type
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer' to type
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape'."

Trying this:

```
 For Each childcontrol As OvalShape In GroupBox1.Controls
    Randomize()
    childcontrol.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromWin32(RGB(rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256)))
    Randomize()
    'childcontrol.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromWin32(RGB(rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256)))
Next
```

Gives me the same exception.

No, I haven't forgotten to set the BackStyle to Opaque.

How do I solve this problem? I want to change the color of OvalShapes using a for each loop

help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecontainer.aspx) has this note in the Remarks:

> > A LineShape, OvalShape, or RectangleShape control can be contained only in a ShapeContainer object, which acts as a canvas for line and shape controls.
> >
> > When you add a line or shape to a form or container at design time, a ShapeContainer is automatically created if one does not already exist.

So as the error message implies, the ovals are the `Shapes` collection of a `ShapeContainer`.  Change your code to this:

```
' get the shape container from the group's controls
' allows that there might be other controls
Dim myShapeCont = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of ShapeContainer).FirstOrDefault

' iterate the ovals there
For Each oval As OvalShape In myShapeCont.Shapes
    oval.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,
        rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256))
Next
```

There is only supposed to be one `ShapeContainer` in any `ControlsCollection`.  So, this fishes that container out, then iterates the ovals to set the back color.

You could just loop thru `ShapeContainer1.Shapes` but VB creates these for you and you cant see them so you wont know what the 'name' is unless you look at the designer code.  Other notes:

- It looks like you are using the NET `Random` class instead of the VB `Rnd` function (the capitalization is wrong for the function and you are passing Min and Max).  `Randomize` is meant to be used with the VB `Rnd` function and has no effect here.
- There is no need to use `ColorTranslator`.  The code above creates a color directly by specifying the R, G, B values.  The first value is the `alpha` or transparency.

If you get bored with ovals, or just decide to run wild adding `Rectangles` to the mix, you'll get a similar error trying to cast a `Rectangle` to an `Oval`.  Use this for your loop instead:

```
For Each shape As SimpleShape In myShapeCont.Shapes
```

`SimpleShape` is a base class common to all the PowerPack shapes and will allow you to set properties common to all the shapes such as `BackColor`.

Comment: By the way I wrote my code like this: For Each childcontrol As OvalShape In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of ShapeContainer).FirstOrDefault.Shapes
                ...
            Next